# Magento Checkout Comment

Tags: checkout, magento-1.9

i'm still a beginner at Magento and try to learn how to create Modules. Right now i'm working on a module, which allows the customer to add a comment during the checkout.

Now i got a problem to implement the textarea, i created a new file called "practice" under `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout` and under `app/design/frontend/base/default/template`. I upload the new layout-file in the config.xml file of my module. But there isnt any textarea during the checkout, even though the right template is uploaded (i activated the template path hint option to see the path of each Block).

**app/code/local/Practice/CheckoutComments/etc/config.xml**

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <checkoutcomments>
                <file>practice/checkoutcomments.xml</file>
            </checkoutcomments>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

Here is the code of the layout.xml file and the phtml.file i override:

**app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/practice/checkoutcomments.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <checkout_onepage_review translate="label">
        <reference name="checkout.onepage.agreements">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>practice/checkoutcomments/onepage/comment-agreements.phtml
                </template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_review>
</layout>
```

**app/design/frontend/base/default/template/practice/checkoutcomments/onepage/comment-agreements.phtml**

```
    <?php

/**
 *
 * @see Mage_Checkout_Block_Agreements
 */
?>
<!--  Start of CheckoutComments module code -->

<form action="" id="checkout-agreements" onsubmit="return false;">
    <ol class="checkout-agreements">

        <div>
            <br /> <label for="checkoutcomments"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->__('Add your Comment for this Order') ?></label>
            <textarea name="checkoutcomments" id="checkoutcomments"
                style="width: 450px; height: 100px;"></textarea>
        </div>



        <!-- End of CheckoutComment module -->
<?php if ($this->getAgreements()) : ?>


<?php foreach ($this->getAgreements() as $_a): ?>
    <li>
            <div class="agreement-content"
                <?php echo ($_a->getContentHeight() ? ' style="height:' . $_a->getContentHeight() . '"' : '')?>>
            <?php if ($_a->getIsHtml()):?>
                <?php echo $_a->getContent()?>
            <?php else:?>
                <?php echo nl2br($this->escapeHtml($_a->getContent()))?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
            <p class="agree">
                <input type="checkbox" id="agreement-<?php echo $_a->getId()?>"
                    name="agreement[<?php echo $_a->getId()?>]" value="1"
                    title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_a->getCheckboxText()) ?>"
                    class="checkbox" /><label for="agreement-<?php echo $_a->getId()?>"><?php echo $_a->getIsHtml() ? $_a->getCheckboxText() : $this->escapeHtml($_a->getCheckboxText()) ?></label>
            </p>
        </li>
<?php endforeach ?>

<?php endif; ?>

</ol>

</form>
```

I deactivated my module and overrode the code of `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml` with my customized pthml.file from above, then the textarea appears! I guess that something is wrong with my configurationsfiles, but i reference to the right block, since the block is uploaded but there isnt any textarea.

I hope you can help me

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I solved the question by accident:

In
**app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/practice/checkoutcomments.xml**

i changed the line

```
        <template>practice/checkoutcomments/onepage/comment-agreements.phtml
        </template>
```

to:

```
<template>practice/checkoutcomments/onepage/comment-agreements.phtml</template>
```

it seems that i choose a wrong autoformat in eclipse, but i'm wondering, that this makes such a huge difference

Regards